# What are the standard bandwidths used on the various amateur bands?

Tags: bandwidth

What are the standard bandwidths used on the various amateur bands?

For example, FM on 2 meter generally uses about 3kHz, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard bandwidths are:

- SSB: about 2.5kHz
- AM: about 10kHz
- FM: about 15kHz
- CW: about 50Hz
- Data: varies greatly, from a few Hz on up...

The deviation of narrowband 2 meter FM is about 5kHz, but the total bandwidth is around 15kHz.

Comment: Relevant to FM bandwidth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carson_bandwidth_rule